# Use https:// AND www. with cloudflare in subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have a domain which I use with cloudflare.com.
I'm using their SSL and have successfully found a .htaccess modification to use SSL and WWW, which works fine IF I don't manually type in the path with subdirectory.

So for example:
When I enter domain.com it redirects the browser to https://www.domain.com. This is good so far.
But when I enter domain.com/administrator (or any other subdirectory) it redirects the browser to https://domain.com/administrator, no www.

The content of the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=ftp.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I've tried other .htaccess rules, but the were causing infinite loops.
I've also tried Page Rules, supplyed by cloudflare, but didn't know how to set up https:// on every subdomain which goes through them, so I would stick to the .htaccess method.

EDIT:

Also tried to use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=ftp.on-filmek.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

But it caused the subdomain to go like: https://www.www.domain.com/phpmyadmin.

Comment: Test in chrome dev tool and keep just one rule to add `https`. See if you still see `www` being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=ftp.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

So here we have two rewrite rules, one will check if https is on and the subdomain is not `ftp` or `www`, on that basis it points it to the `https www` version of the site. The second one checks if `https` is not set but the site is using `www` on that basis it redirects the site to the `https` version of the site on `www`.